# List is not updated after I delete record

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

`JS:`

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import validateEMSO from '@salesforce/apex/ValidationService.validateEMSO';
import STUDENT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Student__c';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {

@track partTimeCheckbox = true;
@track studentRecord = {};

handleFieldChange(e) {
    this.studentRecord[e.currentTarget.fieldName] = e.target.value;

}

handleChange(e) {
    this.studentRecord[e.currentTarget.fieldName] = e.target.value;
    if (this.studentRecord.TypeOfStudy__c == 'Part-Time'){
        this.partTimeCheckbox = true;
      }else{
        this.partTimeCheckbox = false;

    }
}
    

saveForm() {
    console.log('student for save => ', JSON.stringify(this.studentRecord));
    createRecord({ apiName: STUDENT_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields: this.studentRecord })
        .then(student => {
            tthis.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Record deleted successfully',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error creating record',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        });
}
async handleFormSubmit(event)  { 
    event.preventDefault();
    const fields = event.detail.fields;
    const validationResult = await validateEMSO({ emso: fields.EMSO__c});
    if(validationResult.success) {
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
    } else {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error creating record',
                message: error.body.message,
                variant: 'error'
            })
        );
        }
  }
}
```

`HTML`:

```
<template>

<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Student__c" onsubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
    <lightning-messages>
    </lightning-messages>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Username__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="First_name__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Last_name__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Email__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Phone__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Address__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="EMSO__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="TypeOfStudy__c" onchange={handleChange}>
    </lightning-input-field>
                            <template if:true={partTimeCheckbox}>
                                <lightning-input-field field-name="Payer__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
                                </lightning-input-field>
                            </template>
    <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small"
                            variant="brand"
                            name="save" type="submit"
                            label="Save Student">
    </lightning-button>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

`APEX:`

```
    public class ValidationService {
  @AuraEnabled public static Map<String, Object> validateEMSO(long emso) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://app.test.com/test.php?emso='+emso);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
      System.debug(res.getStatusCode()); 
      System.debug(res.getBody());
        return (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
      
  }
}
```

I provided a toast when validation for field EMSCO fail but its not displayed after user enter wrong number

Comment: have you tried   putting  refreshApex(this.getContact)  inside  .then    or  tried using async await.  looking at code we dont know when .then will execute put refresh apex inside it.  or use async await

Comment: Added like this `.then(() => { refreshApex(this.getContact)` still same

Comment: just to confirm  you added inside .then of deleterecord apex method  at end  .   deleteRecord(deleteId)
         .then(() => {    .    not another .then, right?

Comment: i updated questio

Comment: on which js object you are iterating  searchExams  or getcontact?  if it is searchExams    what is the use of getcontact?

Comment: I'm iterating over Exam__c object

Comment: getContact is just a variable named like that, doesnt metter name

Comment: Exam__c might be salesforce data model.i asked about js object you are iterating.  you must have  created table/datatable and might be iterating over some js object.    after deleting you have to refersh that object.    if  getcontacts  is not that variable you are iterating in datatble  refreshapex does not matter.  from your code  i can take a wild guess that you are iterating over  searchExams   if this the case  call apex method again which is poulating  searchExams

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142662/discussion-between-frosty-nah-and-gaurav-sharma).